# SQL query returning results more than required

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, record, repeat

I have run following query for getting required 10 rows as Results but it is returning 12 rows as Results. The query is actually splitting `;` semi-colon separated values in a column of SQL Server table and then getting respective id's from another table by matching those `;` splitted text values.

When I give single `PID` it return correct results, when I give multiple `PID`'s e.g. `(5, 7)`, then it also gives correct results because there is no match between `column` i.e. `name`.

But when I give `PID`'s i.e. `(5, 1956275)`, then it gives two rows (repeated/similar) extra at the end of results i.e. row number `11` and `12` which are exactly identical to rows number `1` and `2`.

```
DECLARE @X XML
--DECLARE @paperID int
--SET @paperID = 5

DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(MAX)=''
        SELECT @STR = @STR+';'+P_AUTHOR
        FROM sub_aminer_paper
        WHERE PID IN (5, 1956275)
        ORDER BY PID ASC

        SELECT @STR = substring(@STR,2,len(@STR))

        SELECT @X = CONVERT(xml,' <root> <s>' + REPLACE(@STR,';','</s> <s>') + '</s>   </root> ')

        SELECT s.aid as [Counted_aid], s.name, p.pid, p.rank
        FROM aminer.dbo.aminer_author s
        INNER JOIN aminer.dbo.aminer_author2paper p ON  
        s.aid = p.aid AND p.pid IN (5, 1956275)
        INNER JOIN (SELECT row_number() 
                    OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT null)) AS rn, T.c.value('.','varchar(max)') AS value
                    FROM @X.nodes('/root/s') T(c)
                   ) t ON t.value = s.name
                    WHERE rn > 0
                    ORDER BY rn
```

I'm not getting this that why is it giving two extra rows. Also there is an order by `PID` in first image but there is no order seen by `PID` in second image whereas query is same. I have attached images for `PID`'s `(5,7)` when there is no match in `name` and `PID`'s `(5, 1956275)` when there is a match in `name`.

**When PID IN (5, 7)**--(There should be **6** records and here is alright!)
[image]

**When PID IN (5, 1956275)**--(There should be **10** records and here are **12** records!)
[image]
Please help and Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need `ROW_NUMBER` in your subquery? And why do you check if it's greater than 0? (It's always greater than 0). I'd use `SELECT *` just to debug and see where duplicate records are comming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I don't have anough reputation to comment your question...

Why are you using XML structure as temporary storage place ?
I think, you can use a CTE expression instead of XML...

So even if it's difficult to understand what you want to do, I have some suggestions :

- use aminer.dbo.aminer_author2paper and sub_aminer_paper in a CTE expression doing the GROUP AND OVER
- then JOIN the aminer.dbo.aminer_author table to the CTE

In all cases, XML is unecessary here.